# Sonarqube doesn't start on Windows and there is no log files

Tags: sonarqube

When I run the program StartSonar.bat on windows, the program terminates without seemingly doing anything. When I go to the logs folder, there is only two .txt document: README.md and SonarServiceWrapper.wrapper. Both do not contain any information that could help me understand what is going on.

I haven't change the properties folder whatsoever.

I don't have any process running on port 9000 (the default port)

My JAVA_HOME points to java 11

Any help is appreciated.

[image: Ouput of the StartSonar.bat command]

Answer (score 1):

I deleted the Sonarqube file today and unzipped it again and it ended up working. I am not sure what I did that was the actual solution. Here's what I changed:

1. Added JAVA_HOME to my PATH
2. Unzip sonarqube in the "Program Files" directory instead of the root directory
3. Updated my windows

Hopefully one of these solution works for you.